# C# what the methods do

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {       
    Panel1.Visible = True;
    Panel2.Visible = false;
    LoadQuestion(); // auto choose question from database and add into Panel1
    LoadQuestion1();  // auto choose question from database and add into Panel2                         
  }
```

When I start my program, my form automatically loads questions into my textbox and radio button list. I click link button2 to make my Panel1 `visible = false` and Panel2 `visible = true` to continue answering question. But after I clicked the link button 2 or 1, it will go back to the `Page_Load()` method and causes my questions keep on changing.

Answer (score 2):

You should check if it's a postback. You want to execute this only on first load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
   if(!IsPostBack) {
      Panel1.Visible = True;
      Panel2.Visible = false;
      LoadQuestion(); // auto choose question from database and add into Panel1
      LoadQuestion1();  // auto choose question from database and add into Panel2 
   }                      
}
```

[**Source**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx)

Comment: cant... when start program, the question is generated.. but after i click on link button 1 or 2, all my question gone..

Comment: i tried, it definitely is first load... inside the !IsPostBack , label1.text="123", when program start, the label is showing 123, when i click link button , the label will change to 456, but very weird is... since the label1.text =123 is show only once,means that is load only once but why the loadQuestion keep on going?

Comment: Could you include the code of LoadQuestion() and LoadQuestion1() in your initial question?

Comment: what do u mean initial question?

Comment: Update your post (question) with what the methods do.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {       
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Panel1.Visible = True;
        Panel2.Visible = false;
        LoadQuestion(); // auto choose question from database and add into Panel1
        LoadQuestion1();  // auto choose question from database and add into Panel2   
    }
 }
```

Comment: cant... when start program, the question is generated.. but after i click on link button 1 or 2, all my question gone

Comment: Please post the code behind for your link buttons click event.

Comment: Also make sure the panel's viewstate is not disabled.

Comment: the viewstate is enable

Answer (score 1):

This is because the Load event happens every time the server processes a request to your page.

There are two kinds of request: initial page load (when you go to the URL) and postback (when you click a button). What you do in your Page_Load method is kinda initialization, so it should be done only initially, but not during the postback.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    if( !IsPostBack )
    {
        // The code here is called only once - during the initial load of the page
    }

    // While the code here is called every time the server processes a request
}
```

Comment: i put the loadQuestion() inside !IsPostBack , but after i clink on link button, there is not showing any question on my page ad...

Comment: What means your question is not stored in the ViewState. I don't know your implementation, anyway there are two options:
a) find a way to load the question into a control, which saves its state to ViewState and therefore does not need to re-load the question every time
b) load the questions outside of the IF, but keep the visibility settings inside

Comment: what is the two options??

Comment: my question is store inside the panel1 and panel2, i just use the link button to control the visibility of panel 1 and 2